# Showing warning with timeout when opening external links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that when a user clicks on any external link (identified by either particular id or class) on my site then he should get a popup with a counter of 10 seconds, after 10 seconds the popup should close and the user should be able to access the external URL. How can this be done? I'm able to show a warning like below but I don't know how to add timeout to it, also this is a `confirm` box, not a popup where I can add some `div` and more stuff for user to see until the counter stops.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var root = new RegExp(location.host);

$('a').each(function(){

    if(root.test($(this).attr('href'))){ 
        $(this).addClass('local');
    }
    else{
        // a link that does not contain the current host
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(url.length > 1)
        {
            $(this).addClass('external');
        }
    }
});

$('a.external').live('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var answer = confirm("You are about to leave the website and view the content of an external website. We cannot be held responsible for the content of external websites.");

    if (answer){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    } 

});

});
```

PS: Is there any free plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a little demo to help you out.  First thing to be aware of is your going to  need to make use of the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function in JavaScript.  Secondly, the confirmation boxes and alert windows will not give you the flexibility you need.  So here's my HTML first I show a simple link and then created a popup div that will be hidden from the users view.

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>

<div id='popUp' style='display:none; border:1px solid black;'>
    <span>You will be redirected in</span>
    <span class='counter'>10</span>
    <span>Seconds</span>
    <button class='cancel'>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Next I created an object that controls how the popup is displayed, and related events are handled within your popup. This mostly is done to keep my popup code in one place and all events centrally located within the object.

```
$('a').live('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    popUp.start(this);    
});

$('.cancel').click(function()
                   {
                       popUp.cancel();
                   });

var popUp = (function()
{
    var count = 10; //number of seconds to pause
    var cancelled = false;

    var start = function(caller)
    {
         $('#popUp').show();
        timer(caller);
    };
    var timer = function(caller)
    {
        if(cancelled != true)
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                finished(caller);
            }
            else
            {
               count--;
                $('.counter').html(count);
               setTimeout(function()
                          {
                              timer(caller);
                          }, 1000);
            }
        }
    };  
    var cancel = function()
    {
        cancelled = true;
        $('#popUp').hide();
    }
   var finished = function(caller)
     {
        alert('Open window to ' + caller.href); 
     };

    return {
        start : start,
        cancel: cancel
    };
}());
```

If you run, you will see the popup is displayed and the countdown is properly counting down.  There's still some tweaks of course that it needs, but you should be able to see the overall idea of whats being accomplished.  Hope it helps!

JS Fiddle Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/u39cV/

Comment: Oh once you have your dialog to the user wired up I also recommend using a plugin to display your custom popup, like jQueryUI, Twitter BootStrap, or Simple Modal

Answer (score 1):

You cannot using a confirm native dialog box as this kind of dialog, as `alert()`, is blocking all script execution. You have to use a cutomized dialog box non-blocking.

You can use for example: [jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Even this has modal option, this is not UI blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Consdier using the javascript `setTimeout` function to execute an action after a given delay

```
if (answer){
    setTimeOut(function(){
       //action executed after the delay
       window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }, 10000); //delay in ms

}
```